# Angular typescript subscribing to a variable does not give correct results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

Motive : I am doing a validation on book name during save - if there is already a book in the DB with the same name, validation error message should be thrown.
I have a method in my service that returns the books object if any books are present with the user entered book name.

After I call this service method I subscribe to it, assign the result to a bool variable and check the bool variable in if statement. since using subscribe/ observable, the if statement executes first and then the subscriber is getting called and the correct value is not returned and validation is not firing.

Where am I going wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Below is my code :

```
export class AddBooksComponent implements OnInit{
  
  bookName = "";
  isError = false;
  errorMessage="";
  isPresent:boolean = false;
  
  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,private booksService: BooksService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  saveBooks() {   
    if(this.checkBookExistenance()) {
      this.isError = true
      this.errorMessage="The provided book name is already exists."
    } else {     
      this.bsModalRef.hide()
    }
  }

  checkPreferenceExistenance():boolean {
 
    this.booksService.getBookByName(bookNameName:trim(this.bookName))
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((data) => {
      
        // if the response has data then the book is present
        if(data.length) {
          isPresent= true;
        }
        else{
          isPresent= false;
        }           
    }); 
    return isPresent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Obvious misunderstanding of async statements aside, the function name in `ngOnInit` is `this.checkBookExistenance()` and yet the function shown is `checkPreferenceExistenance()`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.booksService.getBookByName()` is asynchonous, it takes some time to execute, in the meantime the code procedes.
`checkBookExistenance`should return an observable:

```
checkPreferenceExistenance(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.booksService.getBookByName(bookNameName: trim(this.bookName)).pipe(
      first(),
      map(data => {
        if (data.length){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
        })
// or shortform without if/else: map(data => data.length)
    );
  }
```

and then:

```
    this.checkPreferenceExistenance().subscribe(
      exist => {
        if (exist) {
          this.isError = true
          this.errorMessage = "The provided book name is already exists."
        } else {
          this.bsModalRef.hide()
        }
      }
    );
```